# Excel validation data

Tags: excel, validation, cell

I have a problem with Data Validation in Excel. When I move to another cell by pressing Tab or Enter, it works fine, but when I click another cell it doesn't pass the validation. Is there a way to fix this? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any macros enabled in the workbook that triggers some before-click or selection-change events? I have never experienced the issue, but that could be the source of the problem.

Comment: Do you by any chance use a formula to enter the value in the cell? When using `Enter` or `Tab` the formula will evolve itself before leaving the cell, and the data validation will complete. If you click another cell the formula won't have time to complete first, and the data validation will fail.

Comment: The validation is a formula that I have in a different cell because it was too long to put it in the data validation field, so that's the problem, the formula isn't evaluating when I click. Is there a way around that? Thanks!